# How to start a django app with dynamic instance port in py eureka client?

Tags: java, python, django, spring-boot, microservices

here is my **init** file of my django app:

```
import py_eureka_client.eureka_client as eureka

registry_client, discovery_client = eureka.init(eureka_server="http://127.0.0.1:8761",
                                                app_name="django-app",
                                                instance_port=8088)
```

I want to demonstrate dynamic scaling of application but cannot start the application on different port.
Any suggestion?
I'm very new to microservices.

Comment: I did some research and some blogs stated that django lacks multiple setting files for different environments, unlike spring boot. It also lacks a flexible configuration without code alteration. How can I then build a robust microservice component using django?

Comment: any suggestions?